# Реализация навигации по вложенным спискам, с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Нужно реализовать навигацию по дереву вложенных списков, с помощью jQuery. Ошибка в выборе следующего элемента. Нужно выбирать только первый элемент вложенного списка. При .children выбирает все, а .first не работает почему-то

```js
(function () {
            function moveLeft() {
                $('.active').removeClass().parent().addClass('active')
            };

            function moveUp() {
                $('.active').removeClass().prev().addClass('active')
            };

            function moveRight() {
                $('.active').removeClass().children().addClass('active')
            };

            function moveDown() {
                $('.active').removeClass().next().addClass('active')
            };
            document.onkeydown = function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    moveLeft();
                    break;
                case 38:
                    moveUp();
                    break;
                case 39:
                    moveRight();
                    break;
                case 40:
                    moveDown();
                    break;
                }
            };
        })();
```

```css
        ul li.active {
            background-color: yellow;
            color: blue;
        }
        
        ul li.active > ul {
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="active">li1
            <ul>
                <li>sub li1
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li2
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li3
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li4
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li5
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>li2
            <ul>
                <li>sub li1
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li2
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li3
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li4
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>sub li5
                    <ul>
                        <li>child1</li>
                        <li>child2</li>
                        <li>child3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Для выбора элемента из списка можно воспользоваться [функцией eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Рабочий код в ответе внизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `moveRight()` используй `$('.active').removeClass().children().children().first()`, а в `moveLeft()` используй `$('.active').removeClass().parent().parent().addClass('active')`, так как у тебя в промежутках между `<li>` есть `<ul>`. Рабочий код на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qr9dpat/)

```
(function () {
    function moveLeft() {
        if ($('.active').parent().parent().is("li")){
            $('.active').removeClass().parent().parent().addClass('active')
        }
    };

    function moveUp() {
        if ($('.active').prev().is("li")){
             $('.active').removeClass().prev().addClass('active')
        }
    };

    function moveRight() {
        if ($('.active').children().children().first().is("li")){
            $('.active').removeClass().children().children().first().addClass('active')
        }
    };

    function moveDown() {
        if ($('.active').next().is("li")){
            $('.active').removeClass().next().addClass('active')
        }
    };
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                moveLeft();
                break;
            case 38:
                moveUp();
                break;
            case 39:
                 moveRight();
                 break;
            case 40:
                  moveDown();
                  break;
         }
    };
})();
```